# Как скопировать данные одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется две идентичные таблицы, пусть table1, table2, но одна таблица заполнена данными, а вторая только наполовину. В таблицах есть такие поля: id, user_id, youtube, ball.
В двух таблицах заполнено только поле youtube, в котором ссылка на ютуб, т.е. в двух таблицах находятся данные пользователей: youtube, ball, поле youtube уже заполнено в двух таблицах одинаково. Это поле youtube является как ключом, по которому нужно скопировать теперь поле ball из таблица table1  в таблицу table2.
Поле id, user_id отличаются в двух таблицах, нельзя соединять таблицы с помощью join.
Вобщем нужно сделать примерно такой запрос:
скопировать поле table1.ball в поле table2.ball, где table1.youtube=table2.youtube
Подскажите, как это сделать?
если отправить такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 join `table2` t2 on t1.youtube=t2.youtube
```

то вместо имеющихся допустим 30 строк возвратится примерно 2000 строк.
Я конечно знаю, что тут нужно применять update  и наверно вложенный select, но как это сделать ещё не придумал

Comment: *Это поле youtube является как ключом, по которому нужно скопировать*  А оно хотя бы уникально?

Comment: @Akina да, поле youtube уникально

Comment: (Тем более) Тогда непонятна фраза *вместо имеющихся допустим 30 строк возвратится примерно 2000 строк* - перемножение 2 таблиц с 30 записями не может дать больше 900 записей...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё правильно, вам нужен [`update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

```
update table2, table1
set table2.ball = table1.ball
where table2.youtube = table1.youtube
```

В [мануалах](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) всё достаточно подробно расписано, в конце статьи как раз ваш случай.